# Should image loader run on a different thread pool than the AsyncTask thread pool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-glide

I'm currently writing an app for Android and am wondering if it's considered a good idea or bad idea to run my Glide/Picasso/OkHttp systems on the AsyncTask thread pool? The upsides to me are that you would have a managed sized thread pool and you would not be making more than one pool, which seems a bit overkill. And it would also make device testing a bit more simple, since the async thread executor hooks into the android testing framework when waiting for results. But is this considered a good or bad idea? I'm also not seeing any documentation on how to ideally do this. Any advice or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: e.g. Volley handles threading for network calls on your behalf. do you still need to manage thread separately?